# Checking item Id with selected Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is in my Controller and i am trying to populate the dropdown list with items. I am already populating based on active items but i also want to add the item that was previously selected even if it is now inactive. I wanted to check in the Where clause to get active items but i also want to add an 'or' to get the id of the party type that was selected previously to the party type Id in the list.

```
viewModel.AvailablePartyTypes =
            _partyTypeRepository.FindAll().OrderBy(o => o.Description).Where(a => a.IsActive).ToSelectList(
                "PartyTypeId", "Description", viewModel.PartyTypeId.ToString());
```

This is what i am trying to get:

```
Where(a=>a.IsActive || selected.PartyTypeId == PartyTypeId)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I am overlooking something but isn't it as simple as:

```
Where(a=>a.IsActive || selected.PartyTypeId == a.PartyTypeId)
```

edit:

If it gets complex refactor it to a method call like:

```
Where(a=> UseItem(a))

private static bool UseItem(object a)
    {
        bool result = a.IsActive;
        //etc
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This works have way for me. Some of my where clauses are like: 
Where(a=>a.IsActive ?? false || a.PartyTypeId == ViewModel.PartyTypeId) the false goes invisible and it doesn't get active items.

Comment: When having complex lambda's consider replacing them by method calls.

Comment: Thanks for the help i was able to play around and figure out another way as a solution which just happened to be similar to your first suggestion. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

not really sure why my answer was deleted. Even though others have helped but the way i got my answer and formed wasn't really generated from the person who helped. I had it already posted in my original post to the question.